# How can i undo a git add after the commit?

Tags: git, github

Basically i added the `env/` by mistake and committed then noticed once the push was taking forever and quickly stopped it.

How can i undo my `env/` add?

Comment: The kosher answer: `git revert HEAD`. Less kosher and really only if you haven't shared this with anyone else yet: `git reset HEAD~`

Comment: what does kosher even mean.

Comment: Ah, sorry: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kosher. And I take it your `remote` did NOT get updated? Also I assume you have no further commit on top. You could still do `git rebase -i` I guess if you did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo the most recent commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you interrupted the push, the odds are the remote wasn't updated; but the first thing to do is to verify that (and make sure the remote is in a consistent state).  I'd expect it to probably be ok, but at least I'd do a simple check.  For example, if you were pushing to `master` you could

```
git fetch
git log origin/master
```

and make sure it is still pointed to a commit that doesn't include your changes.

If that's good, then you can safely edit the history of your local branch and then re-dp the push.

If only the most recent commit was affected, you can

```
git rm --cached -r env
git commit --amend
```

If earlier commits were also affected, then you might want to use `git filter-branch` with an `index-filter`.  This is a little more involved, so you'd want to consult the `git filter-branch` docs (which spell out examples of solving problems just like this).